# Getting first Bluetooth device in Android

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth application, which searched for near by Bluetooth devices. It returns device list after a complete search. What I want is it should return as soon as it finds first device and then search for other. Currently I am receiving list of devices in broadcast receiver. Is it possible ?

Comment: solved this. I was receiving values on complete receiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by registering receiver on`BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND`